# stringByAppendingPathComponent, hows it work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

## EDIT_v002

I have had a look at all the comments and I am starting to see what I should be doing. To that end I have modified my code (see below) I have changed newPath to a NSString, removed the [[alloc] init] and the end [release] as its now handled by the system. I am using stringByAppendingPathComponent, letting it add a separator between rootPath and fileName before its assigned to the NSString. It does work, and I ran it through the static analyser with no problems.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
// DISC: FILEWALKER ..... (cocoa_fileWalker.m)
// DESC: List all "*.png" files in specified directory
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSString *fileName;
    NSDictionary *attrDir;
    NSError *myError;
    NSNumber *fileSize;
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *rootPath = [@"~/Pictures/Ren/PRMan" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *newPath;

    NSLog(@"Home: %@",rootPath);

    for(fileName in [manager enumeratorAtPath:rootPath]){
        if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqual:@"png"]) {    

            newPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];   
            attrDir = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:newPath error:&myError];
            fileSize = [attrDir objectForKey: @"NSFileSize"];
            NSLog(@"File: %@ Size: %@", newPath, fileSize);
        }
    }
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
// ------------------------------------------------------------------- **
```

gary

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> stringByAppendingPathComponent, hows it work?

Simple. You want to append a path component. You send that message to the string you want to append a path component to, passing the path component you want to append.

Path components are not the slashes; if they were, the `pathComponents` method would return nothing but an array of slashes. Path components are the parts *between* the slashes (although there is a special case, described in the definition of `pathComponents`).

The slash is the path *separator*. This is hard-coded inside of Cocoa; it's currently (and likely to always be) a slash. So, if you really wanted to append a slash to a string, the most likely reason would be that you want to append a path *separator*, not a path *component*.

> ```
>     [newPath setString:rootPath];
>     [newPath appendString:@"/"];
>     [newPath appendString:fileName];
> ```

`fileName` is the component you want to add. Use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and pass `fileName`, not a slash.

As for whether your example leaks: Well, does an object fall out of scope without getting released? The answer to that question is the answer to whether it's a leak. If you're not sure, review [the memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html).

Comment: So in essence you supply the path components and stringByAppendingPathComponent adds the seperator? Also I can't see how you say it doesn't work, on my system it lists all 4 of the EXR images in the path. Basically newPath is first allocated, then simply gets reset and rebuild each time round the loop, ultimately getting release at the end.

Comment: Yes. You normally only supply one path component, but a subpath works just as well.

Comment: Also: You're correct about `newPath`. Sorry for the confusion on that; I didn't see your `setString:` message. I've deleted the paragraph, since it doesn't apply to the code in the current version of your question.

Comment: NP at all, did you see the updated version at the top. It feels right (based on my knowledge so far) and more importantly works.

Comment: I referred to it in my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, basically stringByAppendingPathComponent will add anything you pass to it to the target string.

Comment: The documentation ([iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:), [Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:)) has a truth-table showing that it handles the slash for you automatically.

Answer (score 5):

You don't append the delimiter. You append the next path component (eg filename, dir, etc). This avoids you needing to know the delimiter for your particular system.

```
NSMutableString* mutablePath = [NSMutableString string];
NSString* fullPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];

[mutablePath setString:fullPath]; // OK to setString: of Mutable with non-Mutable
[mutablePath appendString:someOtherString]; // This won't cause an exception

// Example to clarify on comments below
{
    // This will cause a compiler warning.
    // warning: incompatible Objective-C types assigning
    //    ‘struct NSString *’, expected ‘struct NSMutableString *’
    NSMutableString* ms = [@"FOO" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BAR"];
}
```

There is a fairly clear example in [the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_)

Comment: [testPath setString:[@"TEST_" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"]]; just curious, testPath is NSMutableString, does that work in this situation?

Comment: just curious, if something returns an NSString and you assign it to an NSMutableString I would assume that ok?

Comment: If you do that and then try to modify the string, you'll get an exception, since the immutable string won't respond to the selector from NSMutableString.

Comment: I added some code and comments above to try to make this clearer.

Answer (score 5):

All the existing answers are leaking the original `testPath` string. For something as simple as this, why has nobody recommended [`-[NSMutableString appendString:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString:) intead?

```
[testPath appendString:@"/"];
```

There's no equivalent to `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` for NSMutableString, but it looks like he's just trying to add a slash, not a path component anyway. If you really wanted to add a path component, you could do this:

```
[testPath setString:[testPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"..."]];
```

It's an annoying workaround, but as @dreamlax points out, `-stringByAppendingPathComponent:` always returns an immutable string, even when called on an NSMutableString object. :-(

Comment: NSMutableString *is* an NSString, and thus has stringByAppendingPathComponent.

Comment: I understand that, but it still returns a new autoreleased string, rather than modifying the contents of the mutable string, as one might expect if there were a method called `-appendPathComponent:` as well.

Comment: It seems like this is the simplest way to get what the original asker wanted, and have the result still be a NSMutableString.

Comment: i suggested stringByAppendingString way back

Comment: You did, but without storing the result to a variable, it doesn't fully solve the OP's problem, which was that the `testPath` wasn't modified. All in all, `-stringByAppendingString:` isn't a good solution for a mutable string.

Answer (score 2):

`-stringByAppendingPathComponent` returns a new immutable string, it doesn't modify the original. You have to use the return value of this method.

Answer (score 1):

The last line should be:

```
testPath = [testPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"];
```

Comment: This would turn `testPath` into an `NSString` when it has been declared and allocated as a mutable string.

Comment: Furthermore, the original `testPath` string is now leaked, since it wasn't autoreleased.

Answer (score 0):

```
[testPath stringByAppendingString:@"/"]
```