# Objective-C: too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2 error

Tags: objective-c

Below is my code, suppost I want to get the image from web and save it inside my device, but the error occur that I cant solve, please help.

```
for ( int i=1; i<=numberOfSlides; i++) {
    NSString *picURLstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/Slide%d.jpg", i] ;
    NSURL *picURL = [NSURL URLWithString:picURLstring] ;
    UIImage *Slide = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:picURL]];

    NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPostion = [path objectAtIndex:0] ;
    docPostion = [docPostion stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Slide%d.png",i];
}
```

The error happen it the line:

```
docPostion = [docPostion stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Slide%d.png",i];
```

I want to save the image into the name according to the variable i, I guaranty that this code is right in C language, but now in objective-c I dont know why I cant do so.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: "I guaranty that this code is right in C language" - no, it isn't. Don't make assumptions about format strings - they're not everywhere. Obviously, you have to reconstruct the path using a separate call to `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, you can't just expect all methods to take format strings as arguments. (Read the docs, seriously...)

Comment: (And by the way, since Objective-C is a superset of C, everything which is valid in C is also valid in Objective-C...)

Answer (score 2):

Not all Objective C methods take format strings as arguments/parameters. You need to wrap your string around a `NSString stringWithFormat:` call like so

```
docPostion = [docPostion stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slide%d.png",i]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
docPostion = [docPostion stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Slide%d.png",i];
```

use

```
docPostion = [docPostion stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slide%d.png",i]];
```

You cannot use a format string with any NSString method, only certain methods (generally with the word `format` in their name).

Answer (score 0):

Method `stringByAppendingPathComponent` takes one variable as argument here you are passing 2. (first `"Slide%d.png"` then `i` after comma).  That's why it producing this error. Here is a [good description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489522/stringbyappendingpathcomponent-hows-it-work) how `stringByAppendingPathComponent` works.